# How would you find the pdf of a collection of independent random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

How would one find the probability density function of the following common distribution?

$$
P(X_{i} \leq x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc} 0 ~&\text{if}~ x \lt 0  \\
x/\beta ~&\text{if}~ 0 \leq x \leq \beta \\
1 &~\text{if}~ x \gt \beta \end{array}
\right. 
$$

Comment: Take the derivative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nice cases where the PDF exists, it is just the derivative of the CDF, since we can write the CDF as $$ P(X\le x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)dt$$ and recall that the fundamental theorem of calculus says $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)dt = f_X(x).$$

Comment: Added something I missed to the question, so the PDF is just 1/beta?

Comment: ...between $0$ and $\beta$.... yes.

Comment: @GooJ Also known as the uniform distribution on $[0,\beta].$